# Model does not persist using uib-typeahead with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to use `uib-typeahead` to select one or more objects (via an `ng-repeat`), but facing an issue where the model does not persist when adding another object.

This is reproduced [on Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZcJtwVG1P7Mm0cO52tL?p=preview) (based on [ui-bootstrap's demo](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)). (Reproduce the error by selecting a state, then clicking "Select another". The previously selected state disappears!)

What is causing the model to not persist? How can this be fixed? Is it an issue with `uib-typeahead`? Or the `ng-repeat` scope?

NB: I am also using a custom ngModel formatter, but that doesn't appear to be causing any issue; the issue remains when removing the `format-state` directive.

I have tried setting `ng-model-options`, to no avail.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've went over your plunk and then tried to reproduce it and couldn't figure out what's the directive's problem with `ng-repeat`. maybe I'me missing something, maybe it's an issue, you might want to ask this question at their github issue tracker.

But I've found that by binding the model value to a model property rather than a model itself does make everything work fine.

Instead of

```
ng-model="selected"
```

Use this

```
ng-model="selected.state"
```

and it now [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/9c7JdKTMsrOoMuNZLmke?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks @svarog. Did you manage to reproduce the error? For me, the behaviour was the same on Chrome 50 and Firefox 44. Thanks for the solution - I'll also raise an issue on Github.

Comment: I didn't see any error, just that the data didn't properly bind, I tested with FF45/46

Comment: Ok - thanks. From [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2922) it is to do with the isolate scope of the ng-repeat.