# AngularJS uib-typeahead appears to break interpolation for rest of page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm running into an issue with AngularJS 1.50. Interpolation stops working after the following code.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" 
       placeholder="{{ shouldInterpolateButDoesnt }}" 
       typeahead-on-select="aGreatFunction($item)"
       ng-model="selectedDog" 
       uib-typeahead="dog.label for dog in dogList | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-min-length="1"/>
```

On the rendered HTML page, the placeholder appears with the `{{}}` in tact. Additionally, all interpolation after this point breaks as well.

If I delete this line from the page, all future interpolation works again.

I think I've narrowed the problem down to `uib-typeahead` because if I delete this single attribute from the above code, all interpolation works.

I tried changing the model value as per this post: [Model does not persist using uib-typeahead with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872456/model-does-not-persist-using-uib-typeahead-with-ng-repeat) . Now, I'm really at a loss for where to go next.

Console throws the following error:

```
angular.js:13236 TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined
    at watchFnToHumanReadableString (<anonymous>:703:19)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$watch (<anonymous>:735:28)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:6318:19)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4604:19)
    at extend.instance (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:9855:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:8927:34)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:8226:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:8229:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:8973:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angularjs/angular.js:8226:13) <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 main ng-scope" ui-view="content">
```

Comment: what does `shouldInterpolateButDoesnt ` have?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console log? I don't think I've had an instance of interpolation breaking without an error being thrown somewhere.

Comment: @PankajParkar It doesn't matter what `shouldInterpolateButeDoesnt` has. I have changed it to strings, function calls, `1 + 1`, etc. No matter it's contents, it does not interpolate.

Comment: @Cities I asked that because I thought you had some problem with interpolation expression.. that mean you aren't getting any console errors?

Comment: @MatthewGreen updated post with the console error.

Comment: So with that error message, can you update the question with where `exp` is? According to the error, that object is undefined and causing your error.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined`, there is something we don't see. post your controller code

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. After reading everyone's comments to my original post, I dug into my controllers in search of the missing `exp` property.

It wasn't there.

I searched for the `Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined` error and found [this github page](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/issues/185). Other people were having a similar issue, and many said that disabling the Batarang extension solved the problem. One user posted a screenshot of him unchecking the `Enable` button from the Chrome developer console.

I tried this, but it didn't work.

To solve the problem, one must go to `chrome://extensions` and disable Batarang from there.

This solves the problem but is a bit unsatisfying. I'm worried that an end-user with the Batarang extension would also see a page with the desired interpolations exposed.